# show values in popup window from mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, json, popupwindow

i want to show values in popup window from mysql or through json response. When i click on button, popup should come and show all database values. How to achieve this?

Comment: All you need is how to show the popup? The fetching from sql is made successfully?

Comment: I am facing problem in fetching values from mysql database in a popup.

Comment: What exactly the problem? you get exception?

Comment: not getting the values from database

Answer (score 0):

1, get all database values, 
2, bind view with values,
 3,click button to show DialogFragment or popupWindow